# syntax error: unexpected end of file (issue with if $x = true)

Tags: bash, scripts

for some reason a script I have fails with a syntax error.
Unfortunately no further explanation of what or where the syntax error is:

```
~$ sudo bash bastard.bash
test1
bastard.bash: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have been able to reproduce the issue with this minimal script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# option vars
silentInstallation=true
# work in progress
apt_options=()
echo "test1"
if [ "$silentInstallation" = true ]
then
    echo "choosing silent installation"
    apt_options=(-qq)
fi
echo "updating packages"
```

The script seems to do fine until `if [ "$silentInstallation" = true ]`

I have looked at other questions but cannot find the following things:

- no open parentheses
- no unclosed if statement
- no missing line break

I am quite sure this script worked before.

Note: I use Visual studio Code in Windows environment to develop

Comment: Check if the script file uses DOS-style `\r\n` line endings

Comment: oh no, that might be it. im developing with vs code in windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copy the code snippet on my Ubuntu machine, there isn't an error, meaning that the error is not caused by a Bash syntax error.  Instead, try and run `file test.sh` and check the output. If the output says "...with CRLF line terminators", it means the file is in DOS format (`\r\n`) instead of the UNIX format (`\n`).

To solve this, run:

```
dos2unix test.sh
```

Comment: thank you for the additional suggestion with file